# Why are promises being resolved before success callbacks are run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

So I have code that looks like this

```
var addExpenses = function(parent) {
    return function(data) {
        if (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var expenditure = data[i].RestrictedExpenditure;
                expenditure = parseFloat(expenditure);
                var child = {level: 4, name: data[i].Name, size: expenditure, children: []};
                parent.children.push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

var addSubActivities = function(parent) {
    return function(data) {
        if (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var expenditure = data[i].Expenditure;
                expenditure = parseFloat(expenditure);
                if (expenditure < 0) {
                    expenditure = -expenditure;
                }
                var child = {level: 3, name: data[i].Name, size: expenditure, children: []};
                parent.children.push(child);
                subActivitiesDfds.push($.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/1/subActivities/" + data[i].Code + "/expenses", addExpenses(child)));
                // subActivitiesDfds.push(dfd);
            }
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var expenditure = data[i].Expenditure;
    expenditure = parseFloat(expenditure);
    total += expenditure;
    var child = {level: 2, name: data[i].Name, size: expenditure, children: []};
    root.children.push(child);

    subActivitiesDfds.push($.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/1/activities/" + data[i].Code + "/subActivities", addSubActivities(child)));
    // subActivitiesDfds.push(dfd);
}
root.size = total;


$.when.apply($, subActivitiesDfds).done(function() {
```

var nodes = partition.nodes(root);
    //render

I get an error on this line -

```
parent.children.push(child);
```

- children is undefined. This is happening because partition.nodes(root) destroys the parent property, which is happening because the list of promises is resolved before the addExpenses callback is called.

Why?

Comment: It is not generically true that the promise is resolved before the success callback is called.  I took a working example of a `$.getJSON()` jsFiddle and added a `console.log()` to both the success handler and a promise `.then()` resolve handler and the success handler is clearly called first here: http://jsfiddle.net/gba10h8o/.  So, there must be something else going on in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because at the time `$.when.apply($, subActivitiesDfds)` is executed, `subActivitiesDfds` is populated with only the top level promises. The code that generates the promises for the next level runs only as  the top level promises become fulfilled.

To fix, you need :

- to ensure that `addSubActivities()` returns a promise when all processing is complete.
- to substitute `$.getJSON(..., fn)` for `$.getJSON(..., ).then(fn)` in two places.

You will also find `array.map()` to be convenient for building arrays of promises.

Try :

```
var addExpenses = function(parent) {
    return function(data) {
        if (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var child = {
                    level: 4, 
                    name: data[i].Name, 
                    size: parseFloat(data[i].RestrictedExpenditure),
                    children: []
                };
                parent.children.push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

var addSubActivities = function(parent) {
    return function(data) {
        if (data) {
            var promises = data.map(function(item) {
                var child = {
                    level: 3,
                    name: item.Name,
                    size: Math.abs(parseFloat(item.Expenditure)),
                    children: []
                };
                parent.children.push(child);
                return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/1/subActivities/" + item.Code + "/expenses")
                .then(addExpenses(child));
            });
            return $.when.apply($, promises);
        } else {
            return $.when();//resolved promise
        }
    }
}

var promises = data.map(function(item) {
    var child = {
        level: 2,
        name: item.Name,
        size: parseFloat(item.Expenditure),
        children: []
    };
    root.children.push(child);
    total += child.size;
    return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/1/activities/" + item.Code + "/subActivities").then(addSubActivities(child));
});
root.size = total;

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    var nodes = partition.nodes(root); //render
});
```

The top level `promises` array is still populated with only the top level promises, but now the chained `.then()`s ensures that each of those promises will settle only when all its synchronous and asynchronous sub-activity is complete.